# How To Write a Mocha test for async waterfall

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

I have written a mocha test case for the async waterfall, "function2" is module which call for mongodb to get data, when i am trying to run the same code in node.js this async code works, but when i am do mocha test the "function2" call for mongodb throws error saying "[Error: Cannot determine state of server]".

i got to know the reason that the test is getting executed fast without waiting for mongodb to connect and return result.

can someone suggest me how to solve this problem. thanks in advance.

```
var function1     = require('../../method1');
var function2 = require('../../method2');
var function3 = require('../../method3');

describe('controller :  ', function () {    

    it('should not return error', function (done) {     
async.waterfall([              
                function(callback){                 
                    function1.method1(app.request, app.response, function(err,result) {  

                      if(err){                    
                        callback(err,null);
                      }
                      else{

                        var var1 = result; 

                       callback(null, var1);
                      }
                    });          
                },              
                function(var1, callback){               
               //Here I have a Mongodb Call               
                   function2.method2(var1,function(err,result) {                    
                      if(err) {                    
                        callback(err,null);
                      }
                      else{
                        var var2= result;

                        var context = {
                            "c1": var1,
                            "c2": var2
                        };

                        callback(null, context);
                      }
                   });
                },
                function(context, callback){
                    function2.method2(context, function(err,result) {
                      if(err){
                        console.error(err);
                        callback(err,null);
                      }
                      else{
                        context.c3 = {};

                        result.forEach(function(e, i) {

                          for(var key in e) {
                              context.c3[key] = e[key];
                          }

                        });

                        callback(null, context);
                      }
                    });        

                },
                function(context, callback){                      
                    should.exist(context);  
                }
            ],          
            function (err, result) {               
               should.not.exist(err);   
               should.exist(result);                     
            });             
    });
});
```

Comment: did you solve it meanwhile?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but try to wait when connection (which use your module) is established.

```
before(function(done) {
    connection.on('open', done);
});
```